# Is there a Schur-like theorem for proving $B^TB\succeq A$?

Tags: convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, schur-complement, relaxations

This is in the context of semidefinite programs, and $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n},~B\in\mathbb R^{k\times n}$ are variables. If want to show that $A-B^TB\succeq 0$ and I know $A\succeq 0$, then I can instead show that $X=\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\
B^T&I
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$. This is nice because it is convex.

On the other hand, I'd like to find a convex representation for $B^TB-A\succeq 0$, given that $A\succeq 0$. Of course, we can't use Schur's complement directly to solve this, but I'm wondering if there's a technique to represent this as a convex constraint or if there's no way in general?

Comment: My guess is that this isn't possible, as if both $B^TB\succeq A$ and $A\succeq B^TB$ then, then their intersection $B^TB=A$ is convex. That can't be convex in general because it's equivalent to rank constraints.